# How do I disable the Tablet PC Input Panel in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, tablet, touchscreen

I have a touch screen Windows 7 PC that I'm using for a Kiosk application.  It is never necessary for a user to input text.

When I tap on the screen, a little keyboard tray nudges out of the left margin of the screen.  When I drag it right, it expands into the Tablet PC Input Panel, either a virtual keyboard or a handwriting recognition view.

How can I disable this feature, without affecting the other tablet support features?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Click the Start button.

Type "Tablet PC Input Panel" and click the first autosuggested link.

If the keyboard pops up instead of the Options window at this point, click Tools, then Options.

Uncheck all three boxes under "Choose where to show the Input Panel icons and tab"

[image: Screenshot of the Tablet PC Input Panel dialog]

Click OK.

Comment: Somehow my infant daughter was able to turn the tablet PC input on by mashing my keyboard. Thanks for helping me turn this off.